# Variables not being overwritten in parent class

Tags: php, oop

Look at my code for `AN EMPTY ARRAY`.  Can anyone tell me why that array is empty and not getting populated from `AccountModel` when executing the following code

`$accountModel->setEmail('test@test.com');`

```
class AccountModel extends Model {
protected   $table = 'account',
            $key = 'id',
            $data = array(
                'id' => null,
                'email' => null,
                'first_name' => null,
                'created' => null,
                'last_login' => null,
                'hash' => null
            );
}


class Model extends CI_Model {
    protected $table = null;
    protected $key = null;
    protected $connection = null;
    protected $data = array();

public function __call ($function, $arguments) {
    $original = $function;
    $function = strtolower(preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])/', '_$1', $function));

    $prefix = substr($function, 0, 4); //returns get_ or set_

    if ($prefix == 'get_' || $prefix == 'set_') {
        $key = substr($function, 4); //returns "email" 
        var_dump($this->data); //AN EMPTY ARRAY
        exit($key);
    }

    throw new Exception('Call to undefined method '.get_class($this).'::'.$original.'()');
}
}
```

According to [example 2 on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) it should work just fine.

I'm trying to run $accountModel->setEmail('test@test.com');

**update:** I've realized another bug in my code, fail on my part.  Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 2):

It's seems, that your $accountModel isn't of class AccountModel: try something like `var_dump(get_class($this))`

---

```
<?php
class Animal {
    public $data = 'i`m animal';
    protected $_data = 'i`m animal';

    public function go() {
        var_dump($this->data);
        var_dump($this->_data);
    }

    public function __call ($function, $arguments) {
        echo 'I was called as ' . $function . PHP_EOL;
        var_dump($this->data);
        var_dump($this->_data);
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    public $data = 'i`m cat';
    protected $_data = 'i`m cat';
}

$pussy = new Cat();
$pussy->go();
$pussy->iamMagicMethod();
```

Comment: I did indeed create a __construct method on `Model` and put the var_dump you specified and it returned `string 'AccountModel' (length=12)`

Comment: @Webnet, not in __construct --> just there, where you receive evpty array.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at inheritance backwards.  Your `Model` class doesn't have a $data array.  It can't 'see' the $data array from `AccountModel` because inheritance is one way only.  Parents cannot see members defined in their children.

Comment: @kevinmajor1, no. All good part of inheritance, is that I can define my method in one base class and then just extend other classes, just changing their default props.

Comment: @Tomalak, how? Could you provide some example, when it`s not possible?
I already provided example code, where it possible and works OK. Are we talking about inheritance here, when class B could extend class A?

Comment: @Alexander: [edit] You're right, sorry. The question is broken.

Comment: @Tomalak, don`t you see, that his code is OK: he has Model extends CI_Model and then  AccountModel extends Model. So if $data is of class AccountModel, then $data will be not empty there. Please take a look more carefully. And also provide example, that will show us, that this is impossible. In my answer I provided example, that shows, that this is possible.

Comment: @Alexander: I made the mistake of trusting the OP's assertion that the approach didn't work, and should know better! Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your re-definiton of $data in AccountModel hides the one at Model. Just don't define it again because it already exists at the base class. Initialize it at the constructor:

```
class AccountModel extends Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->table = 'account';
        $this->key = 'id';
        $this->data = array(
            'id' => null,
            'email' => null,
            'first_name' => null,
            'created' => null,
            'last_login' => null,
            'hash' => null
            );
    }
```

}

Comment: It not hides anything. Most possible error is in another place. It`s absolutely similar to have this property just override in class definition or set them in constructor. Error somewhere else.

Comment: Oops, you're right...I've tried and it seems nothing wrong with redefinimg. It looks weird though.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is broken: [this approach does work](http://www.ideone.com/7Fn9Q).

I suspect that your `$accountModel` is in fact *not* an object of type `AccountModel`.

Another piece of evidence pointing to this is that trying to create an `AccountModel` is an error in your code, as you define it *before* the class definition of `Model` on which it depends. So you *can't* have been doing this, after all.

If you still have trouble, please post a testcase on ideone.com that visibly reproduces the problem.